# Using $USER in scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

Given a script which sets some arbitrary properties on a dev server, if I wanted to automatically insert the users system name into a path for say log files, how would I go about doing so?

desired output:

```
/usr/user/logs/log_file
```

I have tried using `whoami`, `echo whoami`, `echo $USER`, and it fails to give the desired output. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$USER` should work. Like this:

```
log_file="/usr/$USER/logs/log_file"
```

however, `whoami` will work too:

```
log_file="/usr/$(whoami)/logs/log_file"
```